# "syntax error near unexpected token `)' "?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
echo "Which number port would you like to power up or down? 1, 2 or 3?"
read string
case "$string" in
    [1]* | [2]* | [3]*) echo "User entered: '$string'" ;;
    *) echo "I don't understand '$string'" ;;
esac
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why this won't work? New to Bash.

Comment: How do you run the code? It works for me.

Comment: It does work for me aswell.

Comment: maybe use space after * in line 5?

Comment: @AmirH That wouldn't change anything.

Comment: it works if you write it in a file. did you try to paste it in terminal?

Comment: Using gedit text editor in Ubuntu and runing through  a terminal

Comment: Can you create a new file in a separate directory, copy-paste this snippet from your post, then run that? Do you still see the same problem? (Don't reuse or copy your current file)

Comment: What are the arguments values you are using?

Comment: See this code running perfectly with no modifications whatsoever at https://ideone.com/cd2JgW

Comment: Are you actually using bash?  What's the shebang?

Comment: @thatotherguy yes it works in a separate file on its own so the error must be somewhere else in the file but I just can't see where as my program reaches there and then bombs out

Comment: @WilliamPursell #!/bin/bash

Comment: Write the shebang as `#!/bin/bash -x` and run your script.

Comment: @JGK same outcome

Comment: As you said you have copied the posted code above to a new file and that works. So make a `diff original_file new_file`. What's the difference?

Comment: @JGK I tried that but when I put in the rest of the code the same error occurs. What would be a more feasible way of writing it? It's complaining about where the case starts

Comment: Run your full script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) and see if it spots anything

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have a 'non breakable space' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)?
For instance between ***)** and **echo**

Comment: If this is the cause of the OP's problem, the question should be closed as caused by a typographic error, rather than answered. See #2 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, coupled with the last bullet point in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Can you post your complete script?

Answer (score -2):

I would write it as:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Which number port would you like to power up or down? 1, 2 or 3?"
read string
case "${string}" in
    [123]) echo "User entered: '${string}'" ;;
    *)     echo "I don't understand '${string}'" ;;
esac
```

Because in your script `11` or `22` and so on is also valid.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback but getting the same result :(

Comment: Which `bash --version` are you using? Try executing the script with `bash -x`.

Comment: This is better style (and has behavior closer to the presumptive intent of the code), but it fixes no syntax issues that were present in the original.

Comment: @JGK version 4.3.48(1)-release